# saving multiple files with different ID

Tags: grails

In Grails , i'm making the user to upload multiple files and saving them to the DB , below is the code in the controller

```
def save(Photos photosInstance) {
    if (photosInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (photosInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond photosInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }

    request.getFileNames().each{
        request.getFiles(it).each { file ->

        } 
    } 

request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [
                message(code: 'photos.label', default: 'Photos'),
                photosInstance.id
            ])
            redirect photosInstance
        }
        '*' { respond photosInstance, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}
```

the problem is that all the files are saved with the one ID in the DB , i need every file to be saved with different ID , how this could be achieved?

Comment: can you add all relevant code..

Comment: @shaydel find the full save action in the original post

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating photosInstance. If you're saving the same object every time - it would lead to the same ID being saved.

You'd have to create a new object for each uploaded file (new ...)

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating a new file object for every file you receive. This is the solution.

```
request.getFileNames().each{
        request.getFiles(it).each { file ->
            // don't know how is your file class but for example...
            new Photo(file: file).save()
        } 
    }
```